# react router default URL address

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to change my default URL address in **react router**.

How can I do it?

for example in my project my default URL is http://localhost:3000

but in a part of my code i want to send my user to another URL like: https://www.google.com/

code:

```
const history = useHistory();

const handleGo = () => {
     history.push(`https://www.google.com`)
  };

return (
    <button onClick={handleGo} >
         GO
    </button>
)
```

when user click button **i want to change URL to https://www.google.com** BUT it changed to http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com

Comment: to navigate to links outside of your app you should use html `<a>` or js `window.location` object

Comment: Just use `a href` for external redirects, `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">GO</a>`

Comment: @PedroFeltrin I think maybe have a way for react-router. thanks! I use window.location

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw I get a URL from backend and use it in new href, your way doesn't answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

history.push from react-router only pushes a new entry onto the history stack. That cause your url to get appended.

To redirect to a new page, you can use `href` in `<a>` tag

Ex: `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">go</a>`